# How should I implement an initialization vector to CBC code?

Tags: python, aes, cbc-mode

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend


key = b'InformationSecurity M.Sc'
message =   b"""yeahcourse snake"""
IV = '000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f'
aesCipher = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key),
                   modes.CBC(),
                   backend=default_backend())
aesEncryptor = aesCipher.encryptor()
aesDecryptor = aesCipher.decryptor()

    
message += b"E" * (-len(message) % 16) # Padding to full blocks of 16 bytes 
ciphertext = aesEncryptor.update(message)

print("plaintext:",message)
print("ciphertext:",ciphertext.hex()) 
decryptedMessage = aesDecryptor.update(ciphertext)
print("recovered:",decryptedMessage)
```

Has been ECB mode but now wants to change it to CBC mode. It says the following message when aes runs the code:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'initialization_vector'
```

Comment: Please post the entire backtrace when asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everything's pretty much described in the documentation: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/symmetric-encryption/

From the docs, it should be "modes.CBC(IV)". You have missed that argument.

Comment: Make sure to acquire said IV with something like `os.urandom(16)`; a non-random IV increases the risk of information leaks if the same IV is used with the same key in the future.

Comment: Alex: I'd suggest quoting the relevant information here; pages get moved over time, and you want the answer to stay relevant/useful when that happens.

Comment: I'm typing from mobile, a bit difficult to get the right formatting)